# Reading Facebook Dark Posts through Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Darks posts are promoted unpublished posts on facebook. Basically it's a marketing tool to post ads. Thing is when a person comments on a dark post it does not show up in their notifications.

Is there an API call to show the comments written to Facebook Dark posts? I have tried `/promotable_posts?include_hidden=true` and others but have not found a syntax that pulls up the dark posts let alone the comments associated with them. Any Help would be appreciated.

(I have done something similar for public posts so I am familiar with calling and testing the facebook API.)

Comment: Not that I know of, and this might be by design, since it's unpublished.

Comment: I found the solution.. 

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/[Page_ID]/promotable_posts?fields=is_hidden,is_published,is_expired,created_time,full_picture,comments,from,message,name&is_inline=true&is_hidden=true&access_token=[Access_Token]

Now the hard part is getting the live long token.. I could only get it using an "app id" that was created years ago finding its Token and plugging it into: 

https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=~TOKEN~

which will list all of the Campaigns and their non expiring Tokens.. 

Without the Correct Taken you just get published posts.

Comment: It seems that the trick really is that it is only available in v2.3 and prior.

I wonder if the bigger questions are a) why did they deprecate dark posts being returned by the api and/or b) was it moved to a different edge?

Comment: Actually, it looks like it's a matter of the token having admin role on the page.

Answer (score 2):

For the new versions of Graph API

```
/{page-id}/ads_posts?include_inline_create=true
```

You'll get all ads posts, Dark Posts also included ;)

Comment: I still get this error insufficient_scope" "(#200) Not enough permission to call this endpoint

Comment: The flag would indicate that it just includes the creatives that have been created inline rather than specifically dark posts, as dark posts could be created not inline via creating an unpublished (dark) post and then an ad with the post

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there, just that because of unclear Facebook documentation, you were unable to find it. In the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/page/feed), just below `include_hidden` is an `include_inline` option which is described as

> Used with the promotable_posts edge only. Filters by whether the post was created inline via object_story_spec in the Ads API. This used to be called is_inline

```
/promotable_posts?include_inline=true
```

On calling this endpoint, you get all the dark posts of the page. This end point returns the dark posts even if you **do not** have the `ads_management` scope in your page access token.

Comment: Does it still work? If it does, in which API version(s)?

Comment: I tried, but caught an error "(#200) User does not have sufficient administrative permission for this action on this page.". My request is "GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/<page-id>/promotable_posts?include_inline=true&access_token=<my-token>". Am I doing sth wrong?

Comment: @Hitest Note that I have no roles/permissions on the page I want to read information

Comment: @DylanDang then you cannot get promoted posts. please check the link there its mentioned `A User access token with ads_management permission or a Page access token is required for /page-id/promotable_posts.`

Comment: @Hitesh Does this still work for you *now*? I have 2.9 code which previously returned unpublished posts from a particular page for a particular date range but now does not, despite no code changes and no (known!) changes in page permissions. However, this behaviour change appeared around the same time as Facebook deprecated Page roles...

Comment: @Hitesh Many thanks. So does mine, today. It consistently didn't last week. Either FB's API has been glitchy or my sanity is slipping... :(

Comment: the page in the link provided in this response does not have any reference to `include_hidden` or `include_inline` options. This is very confusing. If I try  `/promotable_posts?include_inline=true` with v3.2 I get  "error":  "code": 1,"message": "An unknown error occurred","error_subcode": 99. I don't think this works anymore.