# How to pull dark posts on FB Graph API v6.0?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

On v3.2 and under, the method in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49665193/1236326) still works:

`/promotable_posts?include_inline=true`

The results must then be filtered by `is_hidden=True` to find the true dark posts.

What is the equivalent of this on v6.0?  `/promotable_posts` is deprecated and we may lose access entirely at an unknown time.

`/published_posts` is supposed to be *all* posts published by a page, so I would expect the answer to be in that endpoint but cannot find it yet.

Comment: we're also looking for a answer... we're still using v3.2

Answer (score 3):

You should request this.

```
/{page-id}/ads_posts?include_inline_create=true
```

That worked for us.

Comment: I still get this error "insufficient_scope" "(#200) Not enough permission to call this endpoint"

Comment: _The **pages_manage_ads** and **ads_management** permissions are required to read this endpoint._

It is from Graph API doc
[https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ads_posts/]